# Как подсчитать длину каждого слова в массиве?

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

будет забиваться массив до первого пробела
и надо подсчитать длину каждого слова в масииве (разделение между словами "\n")

я не понимаю как должен выглядеть код\алгоритм

```
int wd = 0;
char words[10000];
scanf("%[^' ']s", &words);
while (getchar() != ' ');
printf("\n");
wd = strlen(words);
int y = 0, yy = 0; char re[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < wd; i++) {
if (words[i] != "\n") yy++;
else {
    re[wd] = yy;
    yy = 0;
    yy++;
}
printf("%d",re[wd]);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а хорошо сейчас исправлю

Comment: Неужели даже не попытались?  Идёте в цикле по символам. Встретили разделитель - вычисляете длину слова от позиции последнего разделителя до данного.

Comment: я пыталась но но не понимаю как обнулять счетчик  после того как встретил "\n" чтобы подсчитак к примеру слово в середине и как потом записывать это значение

Comment: Так покажите свои попытки, пока вопрос не закрыли - будет, о чём разговаривать

Comment: @MBo добавила но он не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример работы на заданной строке:

https://ideone.com/3ZhZH7

```
char words[10000] = "qwe\nrtyui\n ";
wd = strlen(words);
int yy = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < wd; i++) {
    if (words[i] != '\n') yy++;
    else {
        if (yy) printf("%d\n", yy);
        yy = 0;
    }
}
```

вывод

```
3
5
```

Comment: он все равно выдает сколько всего символов

Comment: Смотрите рабочий пример. Со введённой строкой всё в порядке?

Comment: да все работает спасибо больщое!